# Best progress on pre-image attacks?

Tags: hash, preimage-resistance

What is the best progress (i.e. most bits) in crafting messages with a chosen hash image for modern hash functions?

Blockchain networks with proof of work are basically brute force machines for pre-image attack on keccak with a target image of `0x000.000`.

So I was looking for some idea of what the "best hash" ever found was.

Comment: It really depends on the specific hash. There are hashes which do not have any known preimage attacks more efficient than a generic one, but that doesn't mean they're _better_ or more secure.

Comment: Right. Just because of Bitcoin we have ASICs that are tuned specifically for it. Even if the ASIC was a little smart about rejecting some hashes it knew wont have zeros at the front that would be an improvement over naive algorithm. And it would be worth good money.

Comment: All those are are enhanced brute force tools. It's not an actual preimage _attack_.

Comment: If aborting a wrong hash is notably faster than computing a potential hash then it's an attack, regardless of O-notation

Comment: That's not quite what it does. The ASICs use a different type of adder which isn't always accurate but is _much_ faster than a typical full adder. It's nothing more than a really, really fast brute force tool that sometimes makes mistakes, but the mistakes it makes are worth the performance improvement.